# WeakHashmap.size and System.runFinalization

Tags: java

The following test passes:

```
    @Test
    public void testGc(){

      final Map<String,String>map = new WeakHashMap<>();
      map.put(new String("Maine"), "Augusta");
      map.put("Foo","Bar");
      Assert.assertEquals(2, map.size());

      System.gc();
      System.runFinalization();

      Set<String>set=map.keySet();
      for(String key:set)System.out.println(key);

      Assert.assertEquals(1, map.size());  
    }
```

After the gc call, the entry with key "foo" remains in the map and is printed. This is OK. It does not matter if I call `System.runFinalization` or not.
But with `System.runFinalization`, the test passes, because the `map.size` at the end gives 1. But when I do not call `System.runFinalization`, the test fails because `map.size` at the end gives 2. Why 2?

Comment: Doesn't it take 2 runs of `gc()` to clear out weak references?

Comment: @biziclop No, 1.

Comment: A call to System.gc() does not guarantee anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868001/what-does-system-gc-guarantees-to-do

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your issue is. Are you confused that calling `System.gc()` sometimes doesn't lead to that entry being removed by the time you do your second test? Because `System.gc()` is nothing more than [a suggestion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--).

Comment: If you add a Thread.sleep(1000) you will see that most probably your System.gc() has done its work and only one entry is left. Basically your problem seems to be that you Assert to fast. (if that is your problem.)

Comment: Note also that none of `WeakHashMap`, `WeakReference`, or `String` implement `finalize` and therefore `runFinalization()` has no direct effect here other than potential non-deterministic triggering of actual garbage collection (purely by chance) or it has taken long enough that the chance of background gc influencing your final assert is greater.

Comment: @ericj please note that this test without finalization will pass sometimes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key
>   is no longer in ordinary use ([Reference Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html))

If you create the key using `new String("KEY")`, it is stored in heap and it seems, as the main thread is not keeping the reference to the object, it is being removed using `gc()` and `runFinalization()` call.

But, if you create the key using `"KEY"`, it is directly created in string constant pool and it's reference is kept by main thread which created it. So, the key is not removed after `gc()`.

As `gc()` and `runFinalization()` does not guarantee to execute garbage collector, this behavior might or might not persist.

Comment: Well, `new String` or not, is not my question.

Comment: @ericj could you elaborate your question?

Comment: No, I can't. It is all there.